# Export only sheets in listbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have a `Userform` with a `Listbox` and a **Export** button. The Listbox will list all the Sheet names in the workbook. I want to be able to select the sheet names in the list box and click on export to make a copy in the desktop that creates a paste only value & formatting (without the formula and form buttons on the original sheet).

So for I was successful in listing the sheet name in the listbox, but I am having some trouble with the export button code, I get out of range error.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim lSht As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sPath As String
Dim sSheet As String
Dim NewWbName As String
Dim i As Long

'Set variables
Set wb = Workbooks.Add

'Add a filepath to your computer below
sPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("USERNAME") & "\Desktop\"
NewWbName = "Reports " & Format(Now, "yyyy_mm_dd _hh_mm")
i = 1

'Loop through listbox
For lSht = 0 To Me.sheetlist.ListCount - 1

    'check if items selected
    If Me.sheetlist.Selected(lSht) = True Then
        'copy out the sheet and saveas
        sSheet = Me.sheetlist.List(lSht)

        With wb.Worksheets(sSheet).Copy
            .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
            .PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
        End With

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        wb.SaveAs Filename:=DesktopPath & NewWbName, FileFormat:=xlNormal
        wb.Close
        MsgBox "You can find the export file in your desktop.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Back Up Sucessful!"

        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
Next lSht

End Sub
```

Comment: Where and when are you getting the error? 

Some more information on what is happening when it goes wrong would be helpful

Comment: I get "subscript out of range" in this line With wb.Worksheets(sSheet).Copy

Comment: it should be `With wb.Worksheets(sSheet)` . Also, where do you want to copy your `wb.Worksheets(sSheet)` ? what is the destination ? another workbook ?

Comment: To a new workbook  created in the desktop

Comment: @user2704742 you want to copy the workbook sheets (that has this code)  to a new workbook (but only the ones selected in the `Listbox` ? The reason I'm asking is you have this line `With wb.Worksheets(sSheet).Copy` which means you are trying to copy the sheets that are tied to `wb` (`wb` is set before to the new added workbook)

Comment: exactly Sir, You helped me once remember.  I was trying to modify your code and ended up here again :)

Comment: @user2704742 try code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following or comments above, try the code below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wb              As Workbook
Dim newWb           As Workbook
Dim sPath           As String
Dim sSheet          As String
Dim NewWbName       As String
Dim lSht            As Long
Dim NewSht          As Worksheet
Dim i               As Long
Dim firstExport     As Boolean

'Set variables
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set newWb = Workbooks.Add

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
firstExport = True

'Add a filepath to your computer below
sPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("USERNAME") & "\Desktop\"
NewWbName = "Reports " & Format(Now, "yyyy_mm_dd _hh_mm")

'Loop through listbox
For lSht = 0 To Me.sheetlist.ListCount - 1

    'check if items selected
    If Me.sheetlist.Selected(lSht) = True Then
        'copy out the sheet and saveas
        sSheet = Me.sheetlist.List(lSht)

        If firstExport Then
            firstExport = False

            ' remove all sheets (exceot 1) in first Copy>Paste
            For i = newWb.Sheets.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
               newWb.Sheets(i).Delete
            Next i

           ' add new sheet to new workbook and put it at theend
            Set NewSht = newWb.Sheets(newWb.Sheets.Count)
        Else
            ' add new sheet to new workbook and put it at the end
            Set NewSht = newWb.Sheets.Add(After:=newWb.Sheets(newWb.Sheets.Count))
        End If

        NewSht.Name = sSheet
        With wb.Sheets(sSheet)
            .Cells.Copy
            NewSht.Cells.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
            NewSht.Cells.PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
        End With

    End If
Next lSht

' need to move the save workbook outside the Copy all selected sheets "loop"
newWb.SaveAs Filename:=sPath & NewWbName, FileFormat:=xlNormal
newWb.Close True
MsgBox "You can find the export file in your desktop.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Back Up Sucessful!"

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: works well, but it creates a blank sheet named sheet 1 and copy's the selected sheet with sheet name as "sheet 2" , it doesn't copy the selected sheet name to the new workbook.

Comment: Your a Mighty Star :)..Thanks a ton Sir!!

Comment: LOL :) then feel free to +1 as well

Comment: as you say..:+)

Comment: is it possible to set the default zoom to 70% on the exported file??

Comment: @user2704742 don't you think you need to gather all other requirements you have, and once you have them, just post another question with these requests (and your updated code)